# sharing session attribute between two subdomains in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, session-cookies

I am using tomcat 7.0 and java 6.
I want to share session between domains and subdomain for **examples.com** and **abc.examples.com**

so in **context.xml** put tag

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" sessionCookieDomain=".examples.com" sessionCookiePath="/" >
```

successfully share Cookies JSESSIONID but when i set attribute in **examples.com**

```
    logger.info( "Demo1 : "+httpSession.getId());
    httpSession.setAttribute("data", "subhash lamba");
    logger.info(" Demo1 data"+ httpSession.getAttribute("data") );
```

that can not be accessible in **test.examples.com** subdomain

```
    HttpSession httpSession=request.getSession();
    logger.info( "Demo3 : "+httpSession.getId());
    logger.info(" Demo3 data "+ httpSession.getAttribute("data") );
```

when i log JSESSIONID in both domain and subdomain are same but when i try to share attribute 
between them it is not working.

Comment: please help to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution my self.
I successfully get sharing session between two domain and now just my problem was identify same user. 
When i try for sharing session data between those two domain and sub-domains at that time it's not work because server maintain session for individual application.

Now my solution is:

In Tomcat server there  is **context**, In context we can store Object and same Context can be accessible by every application in same Tomcat. So Now 
I create on java.util.Map object in java.util.Map object store key-value pair in which key is JSESSIONID and value is user Id who login. So now i can access easily user who login in domain and all sub-domains.

Comment: Can you share your solution as I am having the same problem. Thank you. :-)