# how to make tomcat cookie unsecure?

Tags: java, cookies

I use https for authentication temporarily and then revert back to http, my http website address is `http:local.op.com:8180` and https site is `https://local2.op.com:8443`, and set cookieDomain to `.op.com` in `context.xml`  to share session, but sessionId is changed when switching from http to https so I can't share session.

I try thses ways but neither works.(tomcat7 + sevlet3.0)

```
 1): call sessionCookieConfig.setSecure(false) in one of my filter.

 2): set <cookie-config><secure>false</secure></cookie-config> in web.xml
```

What should I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296438/sharing-session-attribute-between-two-subdomains-in-tomcat

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin, No, this is not what I want.